# How to get Gmail to pop mail from MS Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, gmail

When I try to get Gmail to pop mail from MS Exchange Server 2003 on port 143, Gmail comes back with the following error:

> There was a problem connecting to mail.blah.com
>   Server returned error: **"Missing +OK response upon connecting to the server: * OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 IMAP4rev1 server version 6.5.7638.1 (blah.blah.local) ready."**

Looks to me like Gmail is expecting a `+OK` response and is getting confused by `OK Microsoft...etc...` reply.  Is there a way to get this working, or would it require me trying to convince the company to upgrade the MS Exchange server?

Comment: POP via IMAP.. might be the problem. Check your port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my "comment" slipped you by, but my point is this: You can't access the POP service via the IMAP port number, Exchange replies based on the port you specify.

To access POP, usually you have to use port 110. If that port isn't being forwarded by your gateway, then you might have to configure it to do so. It should be relatively safe to allow the gmail IP ranges (below), rather than every IP.

```
$ nslookup -type=txt _spf.google.com
Server:     203.0.178.191
Address:    203.0.178.191#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_spf.google.com text = "v=spf1 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ?all"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know port 143 is IMAP, I was simply trying the various ports that Google provides on their interface and this was the only one that got any response at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Gmail doesn't officially support IMAP, but POP only.

See following related articles and topics:

- [Centralize mail from different accounts with Mail Fetcher](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289)
- [Problem using gmail for POP3 with SSL port 995/993 to access mail on school Microsoft Exchange Server](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/CTsJkWidtfk)
- [I can't get gmail to check my microsoft exchange account at work.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Da9ETqNJ1fE)